# Issue with scanf and a client SMTP

Tags: c, string, scanf, whitespace

I create an SMTP server and i have to read from keyboard the subject and then send it, the client found whet the subject is only 1 word, but when are spaces doesnt send anything, anyone can help me?

```
printf("Insert the subject:\n");
scanf("%s",sub);
strcat(sub,"\r\n");


send_socket("Subject: ");
send_socket(sub);
```

Comment: This is what the man page will tell you: `%s` format stops scanning at the first whitespace. I suggest using `fgets` and then the input will already be ended by a newline, you won't have to add one.

Comment: Its true, now works perfectly ty!

Comment: I do not see how this question is related to anything around SMTP or even sockets at all.